# Sum of any subset of 20 integers should be a perfect square

Tags: elementary-set-theory, puzzle, perfect-powers

I am unsure about the exact details of the question. But it asks us to find a set of $20$ **non-zero** integers such that the sum of all the elements in **any** of its subsets should yield a perfect square.

I don't think this is possible and am unable to make headway. If any modified form of this question is solvable please mention that.

If it's not possible to construct such a set we should prove why it's not possible to find such a set.

Comment: You surely mean non-zero integers, otherwise we could use $20$ zeros.

Comment: I'm confused. Do you mean, as your title says, the sum of *any* subset or do you mean the sum of *all* subsets, as you write in the post?

Comment: Thanks @Jens I meant that sum of the elements in any subset should be a perfect square. I'll edit that.

Comment: @Peter I should have made that clear the trivial solution of $20$ zeros aren't allowed. Thanks

Comment: Can you get a set of size 3?

Comment: The topic of Pythagorean n-tuples seems relevant here.

Comment: They all have to be positive integers, otherwise you could pick some subset whose sum was negative and hence not a square. Moreover if we can pick sets of length 1, then they all have to be positive integer squares.

Comment: @djechlin I don't think so, as smci mentioned at the end of his answer I think we should maybe think of only subsets of size 2.

Comment: @Aditya I mean replace "20" with "3" in your problem and solve that.

Comment: Anyone got a comment on my answer? Still struggling to determine the original intent of the question. size-3? sizes-3 and up?

Answer (score 0):

It's impossible as stated. Here's a sketch of a not-so-elegant disproof:

Call the numbers $A = \{a_i\}$ By considering subsets of size one, this implies each element ${a_i}$ has to be positive, and itself has to be a square.

Also, each of the $\{a_i\}$ must be distinct; if any two of them were the same (say $a_j = X^2$), then we could pick a size-two subset whose sum $a_j + a_k = 2X^2$ could not be a square.

Now consider congruences modulo 4. Note that modulo 4, perfect squares $\equiv$ 0 or 1. 2 or  3 are impossible. Hence each of the ${a_i} \equiv 0,1 (mod 4)$.

Next by considering subsets of size two, if at least two of the ${a_i} \equiv 1 (mod 4)$, then we'd be able to construct some size-two subset which was $\equiv 2$, hence couldn't be a square. Hence at least 19 of the 20 ${a_i} \equiv 0 (mod 4)$, and the other one $\equiv 0,1$.

So we've heavily constrained $A$. In fact we can use similar arguments for B = 6, 12, 60, 420 etc. to conclude 19 of the ${a_i} \equiv 0 (mod B)$. We can keep picking bases B, without limit (just keep multiplying by next unused prime), to prove that the gaps between the ${a_i}$ are infinite, hence A cannot exist. (Remember, the $\{a_i\}$ must be distinct).

Then, at least for this statement of it, the best you can do is A = {one positive square and nineteen zeros}.

(If the question was to have solutions, it must have been restricted somehow, e.g. "sum of all the elements in any of its size-n subsets should yield a perfect square". For some n.)

Comment: Your answer is incorrect. For B=6, not all squares are congruent to 0 and 1. For example, 4 isn't.
Moreover, if your argument could be mended, it would also prove that x^2 + y^2 = z^2 has no solutions in integers (since one of x, y is divisible by B and B is unboudedly large)

Answer (score 0):

For 3 numbers, it's an open problem.

See "Perfect cuboid" section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler_brick

Your only hope is to prove that for 20 numbers there is more information given, which can be used to prove that no such 20 numbers exist.